# Excel formula: For each instance of value in column, get value of another column in same row

Tags: excel

I am looking to solve the following problem in Excel:

```
ID     Key     Value
1      10      20
2       5      30
3      10      20
4      10      20
```

If key == 10 and Value == 20, get the ID.

So, I need this to produce the following list: "1,3,4"

Essentially, I'm looking to see if one value is in a given range, and another value is in another range, give me the corresponding value (same row) in another range.

I cannot assume that the ID column will always be the left most column.

Comment: will the 3 columns always be next to each other in the same order even if they are not the first 3 columns? also where does the result list go?

Comment: They Key and Value columns will be next to each other, guaranteed. The ID will *likely* be the first column, but not guaranteed. The result list would go in a specific cell elsewhere on the worksheet as text.

Comment: is there only one ID column per sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attached User Defined Function for that purpose. Call it from your worksheet as follows:

=concatPlusIfs(A1:A4,",",1,10,2,20)

where

- A1:A4 is the ID list
- "," is the separator
- 1 is the offset between your id column and your key column (-1 for 1 column to the left)
- 10 is the criteria for your Key
- 2 is the offset between your id column and your Value column
- 20 is the criteria for your Value

  ```
  Public Function concatPlusIfs(rng As Range, sep As String, lgCritOffset1 As Long, varCrit1 As Variant, lgCritOffset2 As Long, varCrit2 As Variant, Optional noDup As Boolean = False, Optional skipEmpty As Boolean = False) As String

  Dim cl As Range, strTemp As String

  If noDup Then 'remove duplicates, use collection to avoid them

  Dim newCol As New Collection

  On Error Resume Next

  For Each cl In rng.Cells
      If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(cl.Text)) > 0 Then
          If cl.Offset(, lgCritOffset1) = varCrit1 And cl.Offset(, lgCritOffset2) = varCrit2 Then newCol.Add cl.Text, cl.Text
      End If
  Next

  For i = 0 To newCol.Count
      strTemp = strTemp & newCol(i) & sep
  Next

  Else

  For Each cl In rng.Cells
      If skipEmpty = False Or Len(Trim(cl.Text)) > 0 Then
          If cl.Offset(, lgCritOffset1) = varCrit1 And cl.Offset(, lgCritOffset2) = varCrit2 Then strTemp = strTemp & cl.Text & sep
      End If
  Next

  End If

  concatPlusIfs = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Len(sep))

  End Function
  ```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid VBScript, but this works just like I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You've avoided VBScript, this is actually VBA :)

Comment: One additional question. Is there a way to automatically update the cell that contains call to the function whenever someone adds a new id, key, and value? So, in my example above, if I add id=5,key=10,value=20, the cell updates to "1,3,4,5".

Comment: it should update automatically if you insert a row, because you've updated the range that the formula looks at. If not, you could convert your range to a table and use table references in the formula. The table will automatically pick up new lines when you insert them at the bottom.

Comment: It wasn't before, but I modified to specify the range of the IDs as a cell value (not the best, usually, but works well for my use case), and I reference it using INDIRECT(<cell_with_value_reference>), and now it updates automatically. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is the most basic function of excel but since your assuming the artifical limitation that you can't decide how your columns are going to be ordered - then it requires you to use something like HLOOKUP (assuming you can at least determine your headers):

```
=IF(AND(HLOOKUP("Key",$A$1:$C$5,ROW(),FALSE)=10,HLOOKUP("VALUE",$A$1:$C$5,ROW(),FALSE)=20),HLOOKUP("ID",$A$1:$C$5,ROW(),FALSE),"")
```

[image: HLOOKUP_EXAMPLE]

Good Luck.

**EDIT/ADDITION:**

Use the multicat function from:  http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/udfs/multicat.html

e.g.
Sort your table to get rid of the spaces and then:

```
=multicat(C2:C5,",")
```

Or if sorting is too much work for you - you can use this modified version of the mcgimpsey function to get rid of blank cells:

```
  Public Function MultiCat( _
        ByRef rRng As Excel.Range, _
        Optional ByVal sDelim As String = "") _
             As String
     Dim rCell As Range
     For Each rCell In rRng
        If rCell.Value <> "" Then
         MultiCat = MultiCat & sDelim & rCell.Text
         End If
     Next rCell
     MultiCat = Mid(MultiCat, Len(sDelim) + 1)
  End Function
```

Comment: This assumes getting 1 value at a time, correct? I need all three results as text in a single field. I will performing this operation 25 different times, so unfortunately I can't just have results singularly in a different column as your screenshot shows.

Comment: So this is information that would be useful to provide in the original question. See my edit.